Give docker permission to Slurm user temporarily
My group is building a new Slurm cluster which uses a lua plugin for authentication. We run all the jobs inside runc containers and use an oci.conf for the same.
My OCI.conf looks like this:
CreateEnvFile=true
RunTimeQuery="sudo runc --rootless=true --root=/tmp/ state %n.%u.%j.%s.%t"
RunTimeKill="sudo runc --rootless=true --root=/tmp/ kill -a %n.%u.%j.%s.%t"
RunTimeDelete="sudo runc --rootless=true --root=/tmp/ delete --force %n.%u.%j.%s.%t"
RunTimeRun="CONTAINER_NAME=%n.%u.%j.%s.%t ORIG_BUNDLE_DIR=%b PREPARED_BUNDLE_DIR=/var/runc/config/%n.%u.%j.%s.%t && \
    /etc/slurm/prepare_bundle.py --orig-bundle-dir $ORIG_BUNDLE_DIR --prepared-bundle-dir $PREPARED_BUNDLE_DIR --container-name $CONTAINER_NAME --env-file %e && \
    sudo runc --rootless=true --root=/tmp/ run $CONTAINER_NAME -b $PREPARED_BUNDLE_DIR"

Here the prepare_bundle.py pulls the docker image using docker pull and then creates the rootfs using the docker export command. My problem comes here:
The SLURM job is submitted by users who are present in LDAP/AD present in the system. But only root user has the permission to run docker commands.
The prepare_bundle.py is run  as the user who submits the job (who doesn't have docker access).So it fails when it runs the docker commands in this script.
Only 2 solutions come to my mind to fix this issue.

Give docker permission to the user temporarily using some SPANK/prolog scripts and then remove the permission in the epilog scripts.
I tried to do usermod -aG docker <user> in the prolog scripts but it doesn't seem to work. Because when I printed the id command in the prepare_bundle.py, the usermod changes are not reflected here (it does not show the docker group for the user).
Change the user_id of the job submitter to a generic user that I created who has docker permissions
For this, I tried to set and unset JOB_SUBMIT_UID in the SPANK slurm_spank_task_init_privileged function. but this also doesn't seem to have any effect. Still the prepare_bundle.py is executed as the same user.

These are the solutions I can think of and the problems that I face. Honestly, I don't know what else to try.
I would greatly appreciate if anyone has any other solutions to make this work or help me debug the above solutions

Instead of modifying user groups, which can have delayed updates or may not be reflected immediately in active sessions, consider configuring the sudoers file to allow specific users or groups to run the required Docker commands without a password. This way, your prepare_bundle.py script can invoke Docker commands using sudo directly without altering user group memberships.
For example, you can add the following line to /etc/sudoers (using visudo for safety):
%slurmusers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker

